# Trim string if not null in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm coming across this reoccurring problem where I am working with a legacy database and linq to sql that uses the char datatype of a fixed length.

When I return the string it always has padding on the end and if I want to concat two strings in the select statement I always need to check if not null before doing so eg:

```
 return (from person in personRepository.Get(p => p.FIRSTNAME.StartsWith(firstName)
         || p.SURNAME.StartsWith(surname) || p.DOB == dob)
                select new PersonSearchModel
                {
                    FullUserName = (person.SURNAME ?? "").Trim() + ", " 
                                 + (person.FIRSTNAME ?? "").Trim() + " " 
                                 + (person.MIDDLENAME ?? "").Trim()
                }).ToList();
```

Is there a better approach? Can I have something in the database context to automatically trim strings?

Comment: better approch is make use of varchar rather than char datatype...and set default value to "" in your database table...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that option :)

Comment: You could write a SQL Server Custom Function, but that is a lot of effort for a small save in your code

Comment: If Surname / MiddlName / Other are properties of Person object,
Maybe changes the GET{} so do the validation there to avoid writing it in the If conditions?

Comment: @Yuval OP wants do do it on the server-side, there are no C# objects there

Comment: String.TrimEnd() is that what you're looking for! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @MaciejLos you can't call `.TrimEnd()` on a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the t4 template so that the classes generated auto trimmed strings if they were not null else they returned null.

```
 public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    string type = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage);
    string propertyName = _code.Escape(edmProperty);

    if(type == "string"){

    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "private {1} _{6}; {5} \t{0} {1} {2} {{ {5}\t\t{3}get{{return _{6} == null ? null : _{6}.Trim();}} {5}\t\t{4}set{{ _{6} = value;}} }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        type,
        propertyName,
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),
        Environment.NewLine,
        propertyName.ToLower()
        );

    }else{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
        _code.Escape(edmProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd be nice if you could write something more about the template. Where to find it and how or what to change?